# MakeUppercase and chapter font

Tags: koma-script, capitalization, etoolbox

I'm using the `\MakeUppercase` command (from `\textcase`) (but also tried `\MakeTextUppercase` cos I thought the problem might be caused by the math-environment of the chapter number) and the `\addtokomafont{chapter}{...}` command to set up the Koma-script report class. My MWE is based on the following [thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/264175/chapter-number-in-left-right-margin). Unfortunately, adding `\MakeUppercase` to `\addtokomafont{chapter}{\normalsize\scshape}` doesn't compile with the changed chapter format but it does without, does some one have an idea how to solve the problem?

```
\documentclass[
fontsize=12pt,
twoside,
a4paper,
parskip=half,
ngerman,
headings=big,
open=right
]
{scrreprt}

\usepackage[english,german]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{blindtext}
%\usepackage{showframe}

\DeclareMathAlphabet\EuRoman{U}{eur}{m}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet\EuRoman{bold}{U}{eur}{b}{n}
\newcommand{\eurom}{\EuRoman}

\usepackage{textcase}

\setkomafont{sectioning}{\rmfamily} 
\setkomafont{caption}{\small}                                                   
\setkomafont{captionlabel}{\sffamily\bfseries\small}    
\setkomafont{chapterentry}{\small\bfseries}                     
\setkomafont{chapter}{\normalsize}      
\setkomafont{section}{\normalsize}                                      
\setkomafont{subsection}{\normalsize}                                   

\addtokomafont{chapter}{\normalsize\scshape}%%%%%%%%%     \MakeUppercase
\addtokomafont{section}{\normalsize\scshape\MakeTextLowercase}
\addtokomafont{subsection}{\normalsize\itshape}     


% Define own Chapter style
% Pretty chapter pages
%------------------------------------------
\definecolor{nicered}{rgb}{.647,.129,.149}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\makeatletter
\newsavebox{\feline@chapter}
\newcommand\feline@chapter@marker[1][4cm]{%
  \sbox\feline@chapter{%
    \resizebox{!}{#1}{\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
        \colorbox{white}{\color{black}$\eurom\thechapter$}}}%!!!!!Error?
  \raisebox{\depth}{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}%
}
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
  \sbox\feline@chapter{\feline@chapter@marker[1.61cm]}%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{%
    \makebox[\dimexpr\textwidth+\marginparsep+\wd\feline@chapter\relax][r]{%
      \usebox\feline@chapter}}%
}
\makeatother

\preto\chapterheadendvskip{%
  \vspace*{-\parskip}%
  {\setlength\parfillskip{0pt plus 1fil}\rule{\textwidth}{.4pt}\par}%
}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer}
\blindtext[2]
\section{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am pretty pretty sure that i have read that very same question earlier today, it even had a helpful answer. I bet the person who wrote the answer is not very happy to see his effort wasted by deleting the whole thread.

Comment: I wonder if there is a better way but one could patch `\scr@makechapterhead` and `\scr@makeschapterhead`…

Comment: BTW: you're missing to load `fontenc` – is that on purpose? Also you load `german` instead of `ngerman` with `babel` which means you have old spelling instead of the new (no so new anymore) one.

Comment: Do you mind to explain to me what do you think is causing the error? It seems not to be the interaction of the chapter number (in math mode) and `\MakeUppercase` as I thought (cos even be editing this part I still get the same error message).

Comment: @harryhaller if you want to notify someone ping them with a `@` followed by the user name. The problem is that after the chapter font is inserted what follows isn't the corresponding heading directly but a whole bunch of internal commands. So `\MakeTextUppercase` (or whatever) acts on a lot more than just the heading.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is possible with KOMA-Script version 3.19 or newer. In version 3.19 the new commands `\chapterlinesformat` and `\sectionlinesformat` have been introduced. They are explained in the [KOMA-Script documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf).

Here is a suggestion using these commands:

```
\documentclass[
fontsize=12pt,
twoside,
a4paper,
parskip=half,
ngerman,
headings=big,
open=right
]
{scrreprt}

\usepackage[english,german]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{blindtext}
%\usepackage{showframe}

\DeclareMathAlphabet\EuRoman{U}{eur}{m}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet\EuRoman{bold}{U}{eur}{b}{n}
\newcommand{\eurom}{\EuRoman}

\usepackage{textcase}

\setkomafont{sectioning}{\rmfamily} 
\setkomafont{caption}{\small}                                                   
\setkomafont{captionlabel}{\sffamily\bfseries\small}    
\setkomafont{chapterentry}{\small\bfseries}                     
\setkomafont{chapter}{\normalsize}      
\setkomafont{section}{\normalsize}                                      
\setkomafont{subsection}{\normalsize}                                   

\addtokomafont{chapter}{\normalsize\scshape}
\addtokomafont{section}{\normalsize\scshape}
\addtokomafont{subsection}{\normalsize\itshape}     


% Define own Chapter style
% Pretty chapter pages
%------------------------------------------
\definecolor{nicered}{rgb}{.647,.129,.149}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\makeatletter
\newsavebox{\feline@chapter}
\newcommand\feline@chapter@marker[1][4cm]{%
  \sbox\feline@chapter{%
    \resizebox{!}{#1}{\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
        \colorbox{white}{\color{black}$\eurom\thechapter$}}}%!!!!!Error?
  \raisebox{\depth}{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}%
}
\renewcommand\chapterformat{\sbox\feline@chapter{\feline@chapter@marker[1.61cm]}%
    \makebox[0pt][l]{\hspace*{\marginparsep}\usebox\feline@chapter}}

\renewcommand\chapterlinesformat[3]{%
    \parbox[t]{\textwidth}{\raggedchapter\MakeUppercase{#3}}%
    #2%
    \\\rule{\textwidth}{.4pt}
}

\renewcommand*{\sectionlinesformat}[4]{%
  \@hangfrom{\hskip #2#3}{\ifstr{#1}{section}{\MakeTextLowercase{#4}}{#4}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer}
\blindtext[2]
\section{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Result

[image]

[image]