# Help Chapter Header

Tags: sectioning, chapters

could you help me do a chapter headers like this (sorry for my english)

[image]

if the page number is odd or even appears in a different place

I be trying to use the following code: [Fancy Chapter Headings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14310/fancy-chapter-headings)

(appears once at the beginning of the chapter)

Comment: Your question leaves all the effort to our community, even typing the essentials of a TeX document such as `\documentclass{}...\begin{document}` etc. As it is, most of our users will be very reluctant to touch your question, and you are left to the mercy of our procrastination team who are very few in number and very picky about selecting questions. You can improve your question by adding a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that more users can copy/paste onto their systems to work on. If no hero takes the challenge we might have to close your question.

Comment: You might, at the very least, indicate which document class and which fonts you use. If you don't indicate even such very basic information, any tentative solution will almost certainly not meet your needs.

Comment: By `chapter headers`, do you mean chapter `title` (appears once at the beginning of the chapter, or `header` (appears above the text on every page)?

Comment: Surely you'll need to use packages such as `xcolor` and `tikz` fr get that layout.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this one](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37170/how-can-i-produce-a-fancy-chapter-heading-like-this-one)?  (whose answer suggests using `titlesec`).

Comment: It's tricky, but the two chapter titles have their text in the SAME position, negleting the specular position of the text and the bumber, that is more or less obvious; (in this case the error is in using openany; there must be some specific reason to choese openany...).
matter of fact the base line of the first tex line in both titles is at the same height compared to the baseline of the chapter number.